# How to Compile FFmpeg with x264 and libfdk-aac for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, aac, x264

Everyone.

Please understand that i use the wrong english.

I want to make encoding application using FFmpeg.

I was successfully building NDK with FFmpeg.

However, to encode H.264 video made had failed( Codec not found.. ).

I was learned that libx264 is need encode H.264 and libfdk-aac is need encode AAC.

so I tried to build the libx264 and libfdk-aac, But does not easily cross-compile.

Please tell me what I did wrong.

***My Development Environment***

> OS : ubuntu 13.10 64bit
>
> NDK : android-ndk-r9
>
> FFmpeg : ffmpeg-2.0.2

***x264 build : build_x264_android.sh***

```
NDK=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME

TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-arm
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$NDK/sources/ffmpeg-2.0.2/android/$CPU

./configure --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-shared \
    --enable-pic \
    --disable-asm \
    --disable-cli \
    --host=arm-linux \
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --sysroot=$PLATFORM

make
make install
ldconfig
```

***fdk-aac build : build_aac_android.sh***

```
NDK=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME
CROSS_PREFIX=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-arm
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$NDK/sources/ffmpeg-2.0.2/android/$CPU
OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -marm -march=armv7-a -mthumb -D__thumb__"

./configure --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --with-sysroot=$PLATFORM \
    --host=arm-linux \
    --enable-shared \
    --with-pic=no \
    CC="${CROSS_PREFIX}gcc --sysroot=$PLATFORM" \
    CXX="${CROSS_PREFIX}g++ --sysroot=$PLATFORM" \
    RANLIB="${CROSS_PREFIX}ranlib" \
    AR="${CROSS_PREFIX}ar" \
    STRIP="${CROSS_PREFIX}strip" \
    NM="${CROSS_PREFIX}nm" \
    CFLAGS="-O3 $OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS --sysroot=$PLATFORM" \
    CXXFLAGS="-O3 $OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS --sysroot=$PLATFORM"

make
make install
```

When I run 'build_aac_android.sh', shown error.

***log in config.log***

```
configure:2907: checking for arm-linux-gcc
configure:2934: result: /toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/platforms/android-9/arch-arm
configure:3203: checking for C compiler version
configure:3212: /toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/platforms/android-9/arch-arm --version >&5
./configure: line 3214: /toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory
configure:3223: $? = 127
configure:3212: /toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -v >&5
./configure: line 3214: /toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory
configure:3223: $? = 127
configure:3212: /toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -V >&5
./configure: line 3214: /toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory
configure:3223: $? = 127
configure:3212: /toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -qversion >&5
./configure: line 3214: /toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory
configure:3223: $? = 127
configure:3243: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3265: /toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -O3 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -marm -march=armv7-a -mthumb -D__thumb__ --sysroot=/platforms/android-9/arch-arm   conftest.c  >&5
./configure: line 3267: /toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory

configure:3312: error: in `/home/nel/android-ndk-r9/sources/ffmpeg-2.0.2/libfdk-aac':
    configure:3314: error: C compiler cannot create executables
    See `config.log' for more details
```

I cannot understand that error!! I was confirmed that arm-linux-androideabi-gcc is found in the directory..

I want to borrow you wisdom. Please tell me how to 'ffmpeg+x264+fdk-aac' build for android.

Thanks.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try/fork/clone my library. It already compiles x264 and libfdk-aac. You can use any version of gcc toolchains (like 4.9) and supports the newest android platform (21).

You can easily build ffmpeg (2.6 or newest version) from my repo running 2-3 scripts.

It is hard to explain how to compile both but you can checkout the [build_android.sh](https://github.com/matthewn4444/VPlayer_lib/blob/master/ffmpeg_build/build_android.sh) script which compiles x264 and libfdk-aac for all architectures.

You can read the bash function `build_aac` and `build_x264` to see how it was cross compiled.

**REPO**: https://github.com/matthewn4444/VPlayer_lib

**INSTRUCTIONS**: https://github.com/matthewn4444/VPlayer_lib/wiki/Compiling-FFmpeg

Answer (score 1):

I know it is late. I have just come across this problem and I have found your question. I have solved this issue like below. I hope it may help some guys when they find your question through googling like me.  This is how to compile fdk-aac for android. NDK version is 9d

Change ANDROID_ROOT and ANDROID_BIN accordingly

```
export ANDROID_ROOT=/path/to/android-ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm
export ANDROID_BIN=/path/to/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin

export CFLAGS="-DANDROID -fPIC -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300"

export LDFLAGS="-Wl,--fix-cortex-a8"
export CC="arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=$ANDROID_ROOT"
export CXX="arm-linux-androideabi-g++ --sysroot=$ANDROID_ROOT"

export PATH=$ANDROID_BIN:$PATH

./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi  --with-sysroot="$ANDROID_ROOT"  --enable-static --prefix="/tmp"
make -j4
make install
```

then library will be installed to /tmp directory. You can change it via --prefix above.

Comment: Hi @faraway, your code builds successfully and I can include it in my FFmpeg build and Android project. I have added the libfdk-aac.so file to my project, but when FFmpeg runs, I get an error that "libfdk-aac.so.1" is not found. FFmpeg is obviously linked to ".so.1", where Android only uses ".so". Did you come across this issue too? Any solution?

Comment: Hi @JonG, Yeah I came across some kind of things like that. Although I don't truly remember, I can recommend you to build with enable-static or disable dynamic for the fdk-aac configure. Please take a look at the flags for the fdk-aac configure.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg

above project for android includes x264.  If you are good with git subprojects and if you are good with cross-toolchain NDK building , it should be easy to follow the builds.

If you are not then you will need to learn about building ffmpeg on linux ( no android ) . then learn NDK builds on android, then learn git subprojects , then build it.

Comment: I need to include libfdk-aac. don't find project for android includes fdk-aac?

Comment: Aac can be added with proper config setting. Fdk-aac I don't know.

Comment: fdk-aac was not supported by ffmpeg in that version

Comment: This project include fdk-aac : https://github.com/matthewn4444/VPlayer_lib/tree/master/ffmpeg_build